# How to make a batch work with long path names and spaces for a For Loop with subdirectories?

Tags: loops, batch-file, path, long-integer

How to make a batch work with long path names and spaces for a For Loop with sub-directories ?

paths to files will be over 200 or 300 letters.

What i m trying to do is to bulk convert multiple files with a program that let me insert the input file directory path+name and the output file directory path+name in a .INI that comes with the program.

i will need to use a For Loop to get the directory path and file name and then insert it in the ini.

Problems : files are deeply nestled and file path contains spaces.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you have written.

Comment: nevermind i ve solved the problem in another way

Answer (score 0):

I don't particularly see your problem, honestly. Spaces are hardly special in file or folder names, so in any case you need to quote your paths. So

```
for /r %%x in (...) do (
    dosomething "%%x"
)
```

instead of just `dosomething %%x` should do it, as usual.